# How do I can get a clicked item to show/hide its hidden elements?

Tags: javascript, session, meteor, click, show-hide

I am having some trouble displaying a **clicked** items hidden elements.

Find below my **clicked events** code.

```
'click .stylishTiles'(event, instance) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var selectedTile = this._id;

   Session.set("selectedTile_id2", selectedTile);

   $("#hidden").show(300);
   $(".selected").addClass('show');
  },

'click .show'(event, instance) {
   event.preventDefault();

   $("#hidden").hide(300);
   $(".stylishTiles").removeClass('show');

}
```

The `Session.set("selectedTile_id2", selectedTile)` in the **clicked** event is passed on to the **helper** via `Session.get('selectedTile_id2')`.

Find below the aimed **helper** code:

```
'selectedTile': function () {

    var selectedTileId = this._id;
    var selectedTile_id2 = Session.get('selectedTile_id2');

    if(selectedTileId == selectedTile_id2){
        return "selected"
    }
}
```

And find below the code for the targeted template:

```
<template name="invoicesV2C">

{{#each pendingInvoicesV2C}}

    <div class="well well-sm stylishTiles {{selectedTile}}">

        <div id ="invoiceAmount"> KES: {{formatCurrency recipientAmount}} </div>

        <div id="hidden"> tel: {{recipientNumber}} <br> purpose: {{invoicePurpose}} </div>  

    </div>                      

{{/each}}

</template>
```

The `{{#each pendingInvoicesV2C}}` in the template correctly generates several items, while correctly hiding their hidden elements by default due to the **CSS code**

```
#hidden{
display: none;
}
```

The much desired effect is that I when I click on any item, its hidden elements, being: `<div id="hidden"> tel: {{recipientNumber}} <br> purpose: {{invoicePurpose}} </div>` should **show**, hence

```
 $("#hidden").show(300);
 $(".selected").addClass('show');
```

And in reverse, whenever I click on an item already **showing** its elements,again being: `<div id="hidden"> tel: {{recipientNumber}} <br> purpose: {{invoicePurpose}} </div>` it should be hidden.

Currently, regardless of the item I click on, only the first element in the list of items will show/hide its elements.

Kindly help me understand how I can get a clicked element to show its hidden details?

Comment: @ Michel Floyd Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @jankapunt Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @ Garmekain Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have numerous errors along with really twisted logic.

Let me help you to simplify that:

**CSS**:
*We're using **class** instead of **id***

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

**Template**:

```
<template name="invoicesV2C">
  {{#each pendingInvoicesV2C}}
    <div class="well well-sm stylishTiles">
      <div class="invoiceAmount">
        KES: {{formatCurrency recipientAmount}}
      </div>
      <div class="toggled hidden">
        tel: {{recipientNumber}}
        <br>
        purpose: {{invoicePurpose}}
      </div>  
    </div>                      
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

**Template Code**:

```
Template.invoicesV2C.events({
  'click .stylishTiles'(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const $e = $(event.target).closest('.stylishTiles');
    $e.find('.toggled').toggle(300);
  }
});
```

That's all. You don't even need helper and using `Session` at all.

Here is tiny fiddle, representing how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/iStyx/ff6hvorz/

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, however the toggle() function doesn't seem to be working at all. I tried slightly altering the `$(event.target).closest('.stylishTiles')` to `$(event.target).closest('.stylishTiles').css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});` just to check if it actually picks up on the `$(event.target)`. It successfully turns the boarder red so thumbs up. I cant figure out why its not .toggle(300) isn't functioning. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SirBT Did you try the fiddle I mentioned? It's working there.

Comment: @SirBT Have a look at template I've posted, there is `toggled` class added to `<div>` you want to show/hide. Did you add it?

Comment: Yes the fiddle works perfectly, however the toggle() in my meteor code doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Yes I added the toggled class to the <div> just as you suggested. Let me copy and paste, perhaps I missed something...

Comment: copied and pasted your template, still no difference

Comment: @SirBT But `.show(300)` and `.hide(300)` are working for you, right?

Comment: nope... I tried `const $e = $(event.target).closest('.stylishTiles').css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
    $e.find('.toggled').show(300); ` but nothing shows

Comment: @SirBT Let me clarify, you don't really want animated show/hide, right? You just want to show/hide and that's all, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154592/discussion-between-sirbt-and-styx).